# Different grinding size for boil coffee and coffee maker?

Tags: grinder

Is there any significant difference between the ideal grinding size for a drip coffee maker and for immersion (boiled) coffee?

When whole beans is not an alternative in a store, you often have the choice between coffee ground for a drip coffee maker, and for immersion (boiled) coffee. Is grind size then important?

Comment: What do you mean by *boil coffee*? By coffee maker, I assume you mean a *"filter coffee" maker*.

Comment: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-does-coffee-grind-consistency-affect-coffee-taste?rq=1  You may find this answer related to your question, though I agree I am finding it difficult to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: I may miss some terminology here, by "boil coffee" I mean when you boil up water and then add the coffee directly into the boiled water (old style). What is the proper word?

Comment: Some refer to boiling coffee, considered the oldest way to prepare, as Cowboy coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For a drip coffee maker, most people will want to use a medium grind that balances getting enough extraction and still allowing the water to flow through the coffee grounds.  For immersion (boiled) coffee, you generally want a course grind that will slow extraction somewhat (reduce the chance of over extraction) and make the grounds less likely to end up in the final product.